# Seatpost maintenance : removing rust

Tags: maintenance, seatpost, steel, aluminum

I have an aluminum seat post in a steel frame. The post was really hard to extract and I don't want this thing corroding on me.

You've discussed how to take care of the [rust on a steel frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/how-do-i-remove-rust-from-my-seat-tube) and on the [use of grease](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/should-i-oil-my-seat-post) to prevent corrosion.

Additionally, my seat post seems to be corroded (lightly).

[image]

Any tips on getting that off? Sandpaper/wire brush it off?

Comment: I'd start with some scouring powder and water.  That should remove most of it.  There's no need to get it perfectly clean, since you'll just grease it and stick it back in the seat tube where no one can see it.

Comment: Don't forget to grease it before putting it back, that should protect it a bit and prevent it from seizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandpaper is overkill unless it's a very fine grit.  A wire brush would work but it's cumbersome to use on a round shape like that.  Steel wool is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Sandpaper and/or a wire brush would probably be ok.

What would work better would be a bench grinder with a buffing wheel and some buffing compound. That'd get it shiny and new looking.

If you don't have access to that, you could probably do a decent job with a Dremel but it would take *forever*.

Comment: Shiny and new looking -- where no one can see it.  ;-)